# How to avoid SSLCertVerificationError when run Selenium Grid on AWS ec2 server

Tags: docker, selenium, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, robotframework

I build a Selenium Grid cloud server by docker on AWS ec2,
and DNS point to CloudFlare.

I use Selenium Grid API to verify server status.

```
$ curl -X GET https://<my-host>/status
```

[Service looks well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xitz.png)

but I can't connect to server when I run robotframework

This is my code example.

```
Open Docker Browser
    [Arguments]    ${browserURL}    ${browserName}=${NONE}
    ${browserName} =    Evaluate    "${browserName}".capitalize()
    ${browserOptions} =    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].${browserName}Options()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${browserOptions}    add_argument    --headless
    Call Method    ${browserOptions}    add_argument    --ignore-certificate-errors
    Call Method    ${browserOptions}    add_argument    --start-maximized
    Call Method    ${browserOptions}    add_argument    --allow-insecure-localhost
    ${options} =     Call Method     ${browserOptions}    to_capabilities
    Set To Dictionary    ${options}    browserName    ${DEFAULT_BROWSER}
    Set To Dictionary    ${options}    platform    ${DEFAULT_PLATFORM}
    ${executor} =    Evaluate    str("https://<my-host>")
    ${webdriver} =    Create Webdriver    Remote    alias=${browserName}    desired_capabilities=${options}    command_executor=${executor}
    Go to    ${browserURL}
```

[This is error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op0an.png)

This seems to have some SSL error.
I tried many ways but it still not work
does somebody also got this issue?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, I update my script.
And update AWS settings from HTTPS to HTTP

```
${executor} =    Evaluate    str("example.com:80/wd/hub")
```

It should work successfully.